# Error while running my flutter project on an android device

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, error-handling

I'm new to flutter, though I have a good grasp of the basics, I'm yet to get a hang of somethings. I'm currently working on a personal project, it's showing no errors, but each time I try to launch it on a mobile device certain errors pop up. I'm having a bit of an issue understanding it.
I would love a bit of help with this.

```
        /C:/src/flutter/.pub-che/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/auto_route-0.6.9/lib/src/router_utils.dart:27:17: Error: Undefined name 'OutlineButton'.
                        OutlineButton.icon(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/auto_route-0.6.9/lib/src/router_utils.dart:59:13: Error: Undefined name 'OutlineButton'.
                    OutlineButton.icon(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.2/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
              io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
        /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_pays-1.0.4+1/lib/src/widgets/checkout/bank_checkout.dart:109:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
                autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart:40:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
          const Form({
                ^^^^
C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.4+1/lib/src/widgets/otp_widget.dart:32:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
            autovalidate: _autoValidate,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart:40:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Form({
        ^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.4+1/lib/src/widgets/input/account_field.dart:13:13: Error: Undefined name 'WhitelistingTextInputFormatter'.
            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_paystack-1.0.4+1/lib/src/widgets/input/card_input.dart:55:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
      autovalidate: _autoValidate,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart:40:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Form({
```

flutter doctor output

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.592], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.6)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
      development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[!] HTTP Host Availability
    X HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:
      Failed host lookup: 'cocoapods.org'
    X HTTP host "https://maven.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:
      Failed host lookup: 'maven.google.com'
    X HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Failed host
```

Comment: how are you running/compiling your flutter app? Can you paste the output of `flutter doctor` please?

Comment: just added my flutter doctor output

Comment: try to resolve all flutter doctor errors first. If you only develop for Android then you can skip the cocoapods error, but the rest I would try to fix before starting any flutter project

Answer (score 0):

`OutlineButton` and `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` are deprecated. See [New Buttons and Button Themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons) and [Deprecated API removed after v2.5](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/2-5-deprecations).